# HDFS file FTP from cluster to another machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sftp, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to create an Oozie workflow to transfer an HDFS file from an HDFS cluster to another server.

Since Oozie can run commands or scripts on any node in a system, is it possible to run a shell script or SFTP on one of the nodes and transfer the file to the destination server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this task can be easily done by performing, from the remote server, a http GET ([open operation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN)) on the HDFS file (you can use `curl` for that).

Anyway, if you want to do it through Oozie, I think you can create a script in charge of moving the desired file from HDFS to the local file system, and then perform a `scp` in order to move the file within the local file system to the remote file system.